# Mountain Lion takes long time to shutdown

Tags: macos

The fix does not stay, guess I'll wait for Apple to releases a fix.

---

It usually shutdown in 2,3 seconds while I was on Lion. I upgraded to ML recently and this happened.

In launchd-shutdown log, I found this

```
20006079 com.apple.launchd                1        com.apple.securityd      17        Exit timeout elapsed (20 seconds). Killing
20008561 com.apple.launchd                1        com.apple.coreservices.appleevents 65        Exit timeout elapsed (20 seconds). Killing
```

Things I have tried but no luck:

- I have reset PRAM
- clear kext-cache. it works at first shutdown only though.

Any idea how to fix this!?

Comment: Could you close all your running applications and run `ps -ax` from the Terminal (to list all processes running)?

Comment: THe list is rather long, I pasted it to pastebin here http://pastebin.com/KfxY2ULY

Comment: I didn't find anything that looked particularly out of the ordinary in that paste. Do you have the ability to backup and deactivate any software licenses and perform a clean installation? If so you could try to operate from the clean installation for a few days to see if the problem comes back. This way you can rule out a hardware problem.

Comment: I tried a clean install before on my Air. Doesn't fix it though. Same thing happens with the new Retina MBP.

Comment: Unfortunately, at this point there are pages and pages of discussion over this issue and everyone who seems to resolve it ends up resolving it for a different reason. https://www.google.com/search?q=mountain+lion+shutdown+time&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=5oi&tbo=d&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&q=+site:discussions.apple.com+mountain+lion+shutdown+time&sa=X&ei=z_foUOXSEYru9ASe_YDoDA&ved=0CEMQrQIwAA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.eWU&fp=89c8db76974e7f67&bpcl=40096503&biw=1071&bih=555

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the following threads:

https://discussions.apple.com///thread/4424200?start=0&tstart=0

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4339540?start=0&tstart=0

http://forums.macrumors.com/archive/index.php/t-1414639.html

In short, it was recommended to: "removing items from Login Items for the user account and adding them back one at a time while testing restart/shutdown. Also, clearing out the ~/Library/Saved Application State folder and the System/Library/Caches folder and making sure your ML volume is selected as the volume to boot from in System Preferences / Startup Disk."

Also, maybe you have Dropbox/Google Drive/Software Update that runs in the background?

Another thing that mentioned was to uncheck "Reopen windows when logging" when shutting down for quick shutdown times.

Can you tell us which applications you think might cause problems?

Comment: - The problem is with shutting down so i don't see how login apps can affect this. Anyway, I have just ~ 7 logins app. 

- Dropbox isn't syncing when I shut down but problem's still there.

- I have only 1 Volumes ML, no external drive connected when shutting down.

- Already clearing Saved App State and Cache, also I never checked "Reopenn window when logging"

Comment: I strongly recommend removing all of the 7 login apps and then trying to shutdown - it was recommended several times by other people who claimed it fixed their slow shutdown times.(I understand that it doesn't seem related, but indeed it was recommend).

Comment: tried it, still doesn't fix the issue though.

Comment: I guess Apple is gonna have to fix this though. You deserve to get the bounty. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved this by freeing more disk space on my Mountain Lion HD. Problem appeared with less than 50GB free space on the 500GB system disk. Now solved with 100GB free space.

Comment: my Mountain Lion SSD got like 210GB++ free space so I guess it's not the problem.